# Is it possible to create enum singletons in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, singleton

Is it possible to create enum-based singletons in Dart, as in Java?

Answer (score 1):

With Dart 2.17 we have enhanced enums supporting instance fields and methods with functionality.

Below is a simple example, and check [this DartPad Link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c435cccf4ad9eead20e772c72ccaca11) to test it yourself.

```
enum EnumSingleton {
  _instance;

  static EnumSingleton getInstance() => _instance;

  final String name = "Enum Singleton";
  void speak() => print('I am an $name');
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this?  How is this useful?

Comment: Enum-based singleton instantiation is a very simple alternative way that is being used in Java. But until Dart 2.17 enum classes were very basic and not suitable for such a usage. Now it is meaningful to use enum-based singleton as an alternative.
Is it more clear now, or need further explanation?

Comment: Actually, this was a question I recently asked myself, did some research and think it is a good idea to share it here and let people know (for those coming from the Java world) that there is such an alternative.

Comment: No, it is not clear.  What is the advantage of this over creating a singleton with an ordinary class?

Comment: @jamesdlin Head First Design Patterns p.185 has the explanation however I can't confirm if applicable for Dart.

Comment: @VicStalkeur Can you provide more details?  There are multiple editions of that book, and page 185 might not be the same in all versions (e.g. print vs. e-book).